# Replacing a string in file containing special characters

Tags: windows, powershell, file-get-contents

I am completely new to PowerShell, so please bear with me. I am having issues trying to replace some a string inside the Preference file, but the file contains a bunch of special characters. How would I be able to replace this ' [{"id":"*" ' with this ' [{"id":"Save as PDF" '. Also, the * in the first argument is regex.

Here is the code:

```
$filepath='C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 8\'

cd $filepath

(Get-Content Preferences) -replace '[{\"id\":\"*"', '[{\"id\":\"Save as PDF\"' | Out-File -encoding ASCII Preferences
```

Comment: PowerShell does not use ``\`` as an escape character, and while regexes *do*, the quotes are not special while characters like `[` *are*.  I recommend using `[Regex]::Escape(...)` to see what's expected of you (of course `*` should not be escaped in that case, but it should be `.*` anyway).

Comment: so sorry to ask this, but in my case, what would be the correct way to write that line using `[Regex]::Escape(...)`

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to convert that from json and then reassign the object?

Comment: To be honest,  I have no idea. How would I do that?

Comment: @frankjstrike There's plenty of posts on Stackoverflow to work with JSON objects in PowerShell. If you're still stuck, open a new question, with an example of your input/output

Comment: Did any of our answers help?

Comment: Yes i apologize for the late response. I managed to to resolve by converting to JSON as mentioned by @js2010. Thank you for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple example using convertfrom-json:

```
cat file.json
{
    "id":  "Save as PDF"
}

$a = get-content file.json | convertfrom-json

$a

id
--
Save as JPG


$a.id = 'Save as PDF'
$a | convertto-json
{
    "id":  "Save as PDF"
}

$a | convertto-json | set-content file.json
cat file.json
{
    "id":  "Save as PDF"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.*` instead of `*` if you want to match 0-n characters. Also, you have to escape the `[` and `{`, because they are special characters in regex.
Here's the final regex:

```
-replace  '\[\{"id":".*"', '[{"id":"Save as PDF"
```